# Replanting and propagating old Lucky Bamboo tree with newborn stalks

Tags: propagation, cuttings, lucky-bamboo

I have had two Lucky Bamboo trees for the past 5 years now. I grow them in water and they have been doing well. Four months ago the two of them started growing new stalks. The new growth is causing a weight problem and I am afraid they will not be able to sustain the growth in their current situation.

I watched a few videos on replanting Lucky Bamboo; however, I couldn't find any cases similar enough to my own. Is there any chance that cutting this new growth and replanting it will result in a healthy and productive plant similar to the two plants the stalks have been cut from? If that is the case then how should I go about the process?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey great question Mahdi! It seems to me you might be over thinking the problem a bit. Lucky bamboo is pretty forgiving when it comes to propagation. Simply cut the new growth stocks at their base near the node where they are growing from and plant the stock in a chlorine-free water and gravel mixture.

Understand that Lucky Bamboo is not actually bamboo at all. In fact, it is much more similar to a house plant than it is bamboo. Bamboo likes full sun and is much more resilient than Lucky Bamboo. That being said, I would suggest placing the newly planted bamboo stocks in an area with a good source of indirect sunlight.

I am not sure which videos you have already seen but based on your pictures and situation I would suggest you take a look at this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-8-1GZs-tU

GL!

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply, then should I cover the cut section on the parent tree with wax or just leave it after cutting it?

Comment: Sure you could but to be completely honest it is purely a precaution and is not really necessary. Plants have been evolving for millions and millions of years and over that time have become incredibly proficient at repelling diseases and preventing water loss all on their own. I am sure your plants would be fine with or without the wax.