# 5 year old Lucky Bamboo is dying

Tags: lucky-bamboo

I've had these two Lucky Bamboos for around 5 years and this summer when I was on a vacation all the water on them vaporized and when I got back they were bent and lost their stiffness. Now after 8 months they're still losing their leaves.
What can I do for them?

Note that in my case only the top leaves get yellow and they start from their tail, not their tip. I'd seen some questions but they were not like this one.

[image: even some of the older nodes are getting infected!]
[image]

even some of the older nodes are getting infected

Answer (score 1):

Lucky bamboos are very hardy plants, so it has perfect chances to recover.

If the roots were damaged when you were on vacation, than it is possible that the plant can not produce enough nutrients for the new leaves. 
So it could be a solution to **cut you plant into cuttings and propagate them again in the water**. So you’ ll have new fresh roots and healthier plants (just shorter).

Before doing it, just check that there are no visible bugs or fungi on the plant (so they are not the cause).

Just one example of cutting propagation: https://m.wikihow.com/Propagate-Lucky-Bamboo#Taking_a_Cutting

P.S. I’m not sure if your plant always is behind the curtain (like on photo), but it could be beneficial to bring it directly to the window to allow more light.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daria, I don't think the roots have any problems since they even produced new stalks both, which I cut and propagated.
(the original topic for that https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/42577/replanting-and-propagating-old-lucky-bamboo-tree-with-newborn-stalks)

And about the bugs and fungi, there were just a lot of algae in the roots which I washed away, hoping that would help them.

Comment: Do you use any fertilizer in the water?

Comment: Yes, here's the fertilizer: https://st.hzcdn.com/simgs/b5d22e720c8d0772_9-6354/home-design.jpg

Also, I realized both my Bamboos are pregnant (lol) now. One of them has 2 and the other has 1 baby Bamboos on the way, So I think They're getting enough food.